# How to create a fake service for Angular testing using Karma

Tags: angular, typescript

I try to create a fake service matching my `AppLoaderService` for karma testing of my Angular application.

I have a service which handle loader visibility state over my application. It's used in components this way:

- The main component subscribe the state of loader to display or not the loader
- Child components and other services can trigger the `emitChange` function to change visibility state over the service

Here is the service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

@Injectable()
export class AppLoaderService {
  private isLoaderVisible = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  changeLoaderState$ = this.isLoaderVisible.asObservable();

  emitChange(state: any) {
    this.isLoaderVisible.next(state);
  }    
}
```

The fact is this service will be changed over time by the team.

And I don't really care about testing the fact the logic of AppLoaderService will "work" at component testing level. I want only be able to test, at component level, subscription to service (for main component) and returns initial service value and that `emitChange()` has been triggered at some moments in my component life.

So in order not to be dependant on the service itself, maybe I can stub this service to then, in my component tests, be able to use this stub with:

```
providers: [
  {provide: AppLoaderService, useClass: AppLoaderServiceStub}
]
```

**But I struggle defining a proper stubs without rewriting the whole service.**

Do you have any idea on how I can achieve this? Especially the fact one of my component is subscribing to `changeLoaderState$`.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Create a fake service I can call in place of the real one not to be dependant on the service logic inmy component testing

Comment: for karma testing ?

Comment: yes indeed. I modified the post since it wasn't clear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point when stubbing is that the stub needs to implement the public API **that the component under test cares about**.

From your example code, you need an `emitChange(state: any)` method on your stub. If you don't care at all whether it gets called or not, then you can just leave that method with an empty body.

```
export class AppLoaderServiceStub {

  emitChange(state: any) {
  }    
}
```

*(I'm making the assumption that the observable property on the service is only being used by your Loader component, not by the other components and services of your app - if that assumption is false, you'd have to stub that observable as well).*

**EDIT:**

Since you need the changeLoaderState$ observable, then stub that as well -

```
export class AppLoaderServiceStub {

  changeLoaderState$ = Observable.of({ }) // or whatever dummy state value you want to use
  emitChange(state: any) {}    
}
```

*Note that `Observable.of` will emit its values and then complete. If you don't want a completion event to trigger, you might want `Observable.never`. If I am understanding your usage correctly though, I doubt the distinction matters.*

PS. don't forget to import the `of` operator:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answer. My main app component (which is charged of displaying the loader) subscribes to `changeLoaderState$`. It's this part I can't manage to stub without rewriting the entire service...

Comment: updated with additional code example of stubbing the observable

Comment: Thanks, it was quite less complex than that I did. I think my brain went too far for nothing.